# rails windows problem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I just installed ruby on rails on windows.

install mysql and created a new project. Then I changed database.yml to use my own mysql server as follow

development:
adapter: mysql
database: mytools
username: test
password: test

when I try to access story controller(http://localhost:3000/stories), error shows

"SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: stories: SELECT * FROM "stories" "

Why am I getting this error? I am not using mysql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Rails creates and uses a SQLite database not a MySQL one.

You can specify the database to use with the -d flag when creating your Rails application. For example to create a rails app called "sample" using mysql as the database:

```
rails sample -d mysql
```

Taken from the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application) guide.

You might also want to check out the section on [Configuring a MySQL Database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-mysql-database) in the same document.

Comment: how did I miss that??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

From what I know - though I was coding in rails long ago, there are 3 separate databases there: development, production and test. Maybe You are trying to use test or production  and You didn't configured them?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a restart on the webserver?

Check if the RAILS_ENV is set to production and if it is, set it for development:

```
set RAILS_ENV=development
```